# High side switch using complementary MOSFET: pull up/down calculation

Tags: mosfet

For a battery powered ultra low consumption application I designed a classical high side switch using the complementary MOSFET FDMA1032CZ. this is the schematic:

[image]

The idea is simple:

- before shipping, the circuit consumption is nearly 0[A] (only MOSFET and battery leaks),
- then the user powers on the circuit using switch S1,
- the microcontroller starts running and activates Q1-N and Q1-P via "PWR_ON" signal,
- the circuit is then continuously powered on by the battery through the mosfet switch.

I need assistance to calculate the optimal value for both pull-up and pull-down resistors (R1 and R2). For reminder, those 2 resistors are mandatory to set voltage level when circuit is powered on.

In my opinion those resistors must be :

1. as large as possible to minimize current when the 2 mosfets are on,
2. but not too big to make sure the 2 mosfets can switch fully on.

When looking at [datasheet](http://www.fairchildsemi.com/ds/FD/FDMA1032CZ.pdf), it appears that the maximum MOSFET gate body leakage IGSS_max = +/-10[uA] and the minimum gate threshold voltage VGSth_min = +/-0.6[V].

According to previous point 2), the resistor value should NOT be greater than R_max = VGSth_min/IGSS_max = 0.6/10e-6 = 60[kohm].

For a battery voltage of 3V, this would result in a total consumption through the resistors of: I = 2x V_BAT/R = 2x 3/60e3 = 100[uA], which is far too big...

I would appreciate if someone could confirm and/or correct my calculation.

Answer (score 1):

It seems your calculations are correct.

This IGSS is untypically high for mosfets. I think this is because of zener diodes on gate. Typical value is ±100 nA.

Answer (score 1):

The common reasons for including that resistors are as follows:

**R2**: To avoid leaving the gate of Q1-N in a floating state and thus avoid unwanted conduction in specific situations . For example, when the microcontroller is powered but not yet executed the code that configures the I/O system (in your case, to write a high value on PWR_ON) or in forced reset caused by noise and watchdog  activation.

**R1**: As Q1-N cannot impose a high level in the Q1-P gate, the turn-off of this mosfet depends exclusively on the discharge of its GS capacitor through R1.

The exact value of each resistor is not critical. However, they influence the mosfet turn-off time (Q1-P) and determine the battery consumption when conducting (Q1-N and Q1-P). In fact, depending on the circuit used not even a resistor between G and S for Q1-P is necessary (or between the base and emitter the case of a bipolar transistor). This is true when using well defined voltages levels on gate-source. See figure below, for alternatives:

[image: Power Control]